# mysql query not getting values from database on selecting radio buttons

Tags: php, mysql, database, radio-button

I have searched a long way for the result but still no success on this. I am trying to select radio button and hence showing its result on same page but my query somehow not getting records for the same. It says MySQL "QUERY EMPTY". Please let me know where am I doing wrong. Here is my code for that. A help would be highly appreciated.

PHP

```
<?php 
    include 'blocks/headerInc.php' ;
    $errmsg   = $module_id = $query = $date_from = $date_to = $sql1 = "";
    //Search section start here
    /*$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 ";
    if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        if (!empty($_REQUEST['date_from'])) {
            $date_from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_REQUEST['date_from']));
        }
        if (!empty($_REQUEST['date_to'])) {
            $date_to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_REQUEST['date_to']));
        }
        if (!empty($date_to) && empty($date_from)) {
            $errmsg = "Please select valid date range.";
        }
        if (!empty($date_to) && (strtotime($date_from) > strtotime($date_to))) {
            $errmsg = "Please select valid date range.";
        }
        if ($errmsg == '') {
            if (!empty($date_to) && (strtotime($date_from) <= strtotime($date_to))) {
                $sqlQuery .= " AND created_on BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to'";
            }
            $sqlQuery .= "  order by id DESC";
        }
        $date_from = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($date_from));
        $date_to   = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($date_to));
        $date_from = $date_from != '01/01/1970' ? $date_from : '';
        $date_to   = $date_to != '01/01/1970' ? $date_to : '';*/
        if (isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'approved') {
            $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 and status = 1");
            //$result = ($sql1);
            while ($row = $sql1->fetch_assoc()) {
                $users[] = $row;
            }
        } elseif (isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'unapproved') {
            $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 and status = 0");
            //$result = mysql_query($sql1);
            while ($row = $sql1->fetch_assoc()) {
                $users[] = $row;
            }
        } elseif (isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'all') {
            $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3");
            //$result = mysql_query($sql1);
            while ($row = $sql1->fetch_assoc()) {
                $users[] = $row;
            }
        }
    //}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container pagecontainer">
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
        <!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 sidebar" id="sidebar">
            <div id="left_panel" class="clearfix left">
                <?php include 'blocks/leftnavInc.php' ; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 page-right">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">Search Registered Candidate</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="column col-sm-offset-0">
                        <?php if($errmsg!="") echo "<div class='error'>".ucwords($errmsg)."</div>"; ?>
                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="get" action="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="username" class="control-label">Date From:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <div class="input-group date">
                                            <input class="form-control datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Dob must be a date." data-val-required="The Dob field is required." id="Dob" name="date_from" placeholder="Date From" type="text" value="<?php echo $date_from ; ?>" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="username" class="control-label">Date To:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <div class="input-group date">
                                            <input class="form-control datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Dob must be a date." data-val-required="The Dob field is required." id="Dob" name="date_to" placeholder="Date To" type="text" value="<?php echo $date_to ; ?>" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 text-left">
                                        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Search</button>
                                        <button type="reset" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='reportRegisteredUsers.php'" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label for="username" class="control-label"> </label>                  
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 text-right">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">Report:Registered Candidate</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <input type="radio" name="users" value="all" checked="checked"> All Candidates<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="users" value="approved"> Approved Candidates<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="users" value="unapproved"> Unapproved Candidates<br>      </form>          
                    <div class="column col-sm-offset-0">
                        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTableReport dt-responsive nowrap"   cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>S.No.</th>
                                    <th>Email ID</th>
                                    <th>SBI Employee ID</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Mobile No.</th>
                                    <th>Date of Birth</th>
                                    <th>Registration Date</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                    $sqr            =   $db->query($sql1);
                                    //print_r($sqr);
                                    //$i                =   1 ;
                                    //$sq           =   $db->query($sqlQuery);
                                    $i              =   1 ;
                                    if($db->affected_rows > 0)
                                    {
                                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqr))
                                        {
                                         extract($row);
                                    ?>              
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $i ; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $email ; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $employee_id ; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $first_name."&nbsp;".$middle_name."&nbsp;".$last_name ; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $mobile ; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php if($dob !='1970-01-01'){echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dob)) ; }?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on)) ; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php $i++;}} ?>              
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="reset" onClick="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> Go Back</button>
            </div>
        <!--/row-->
        </div>
        <!--/.sidebar-offcanvas-->
    </div>
</div>

<?php include 'blocks/footerInc.php'; ?>
```

Comment: I am sorry but this is a soup... :-/ Can you narrow down your code to the meaningful sections eventually, in a compacted manner?

Comment: **Please**, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and `mysql_*` functions have been officially removed in PHP 7. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you can't decide, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Your missing a curly bracket in your first set of code

Comment: You're missing a `>` in your html

Comment: also what is this `**}`?

Answer (score 1):

Does this need to be strictly PHP and MySQL? Can we include some JavaScript/jQuery? While this doesn't answer your question directly, I hope it helps.

For your issue, I would detect the change event of your radio field and fire off a quick jQuery $.post to process the selection.

When your JavaScript sends a POST request to your PHP, you would run your PHP logic and return (or echo) the result. This can then be "digested" by your JavaScript. Here is a simple/rough example using jQuery and PHP. Adapt to your needs:

```
<script>
  // # on ready
  $(function() {

    // # current document - assumes you'll be submitting to self
    var self = document.location.href;

    // # when changing the user radios
    $('input[type=radio][name=users]').change(function() {

      // # grab the value of the radio and create a js array to post
      var postData = {'users': $(this).val()};

      // # post the postData to your PHP 
      $.post(self, postData).done(function(data, status, xhr) {

        // # assumes you're returning JSON data
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        // # add your logic here
        console.log('POST Response', data);
        // # update an element with the returned data or response:
        $('#example').before('<div>'+ data +'</div>');
     });
  });
});
</script>
```

Regarding your PHP code, as other users have suggested, you're using mysql_ functions that are no longer supported on modern versions of PHP. You're quickest and dirtiest adjustment, without rewriting everything, is to use mysqli_ functions (notice the additional 'i').

You're already listening for the $_POST['users'] parm, so the only addition I would recommend is to actually use that $users[] array. I could get into re-writing the PHP so it makes sense, but here is a quick adjustment to your existing code:

```
<?php
$users = array();

if(isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'approved'){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type = 3 AND status = 1";

} else if(isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'unapproved') {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 and status = 0";

} else if (isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'all') {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3";
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

  /* fetch associative array */
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $users[] = $row;
  }

  // # encode your $row array into JSON and echo for JavaScript  
  echo json_encode($users);

  // # free result set
  $result->free();
}
```

?>

While this isn't a complete solution, I hope it points you in the right direction.

A couple things to note - you'll need to adjust your MySQL connection code if you're to use mysqli_ functions. You'll also need to include jQuery (ideally from CDN) for that JavaScript to work (or you could rewrite it to not use a library like jQuery). This should return the results of your query to your JavaScript. The result should be available as "data" in your js. I've added a console.log so you can view the response in your inspector.

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for the solution provided. But yes I strictly have to use php and MySQL. JS or jQuery won't help. Is there any way to resolve that.

Comment: @anand - you could use either $_COOKIES or $_SESSION to store these values from your query temporarily and then echo them onto page on subsequent page loads. You would submit the form, listen for those POST parms and set your cookie or session as needed. You would check to see if those session vars are set before echoing them.

Comment: Thanks all for the valuable time you have given. Its done and working fine .. Cheers !!